# Inconveniente con findBy en JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Me acaba de pasar algo raro haciendo una búsqueda con JPA.
Paso data:

Entidad:

```
package ar.com.sancorsalud.planesapi.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLANES", schema = "PLANES")
public class Plan implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION_REDUCIDA")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String descripcionReducida;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String descripcion;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CODIGO")
    private String codigo;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NRO_SOLICITUD")
    private Integer nroSolicitud;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_VIGENCIA")
    private LocalDate fechaVigencia;

}
```

Repositorio:

```
package ar.com.sancorsalud.planesapi.repository;

import ar.com.sancorsalud.planesapi.model.LineaPlan;
import ar.com.sancorsalud.planesapi.model.Plan;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface PlanRepository extends JpaRepository<Plan, Integer> {

    Page<Plan> findAll(Specification<Plan> spec, Pageable pageable);

    Optional<Plan> findByLineaPlan(LineaPlan lineaPlan);

    Optional<Plan> findByCodigo(String codigo);

    List<Plan> findByPlanPadreId(String planPadre);

    Optional<Plan> findTopByOrderByNroSolicitudDesc();

}
```

Mi problema radica en el siguiente find:

```
  Optional<Plan> findByCodigo(String codigo);
```

...el cual lo utilizo dentro de un servicio de la siguiente manera:

```
Optional<Plan> codigoEncontrado = this.planRepository.findByCodigo(planDto.getCodigo());
        if (codigoEncontrado.isPresent())
            throw new ResourceBadRequestException("El plan que intenta ingresar con código " + planDto.getCodigo() + " ya existe.");
```

El inconveniente es que, si a la búsqueda ingreso un valor "parecido" de código, me lo toma como que lo encuentra.
Ejemplo: si planDto.getCodigo() es "test88" y en base de datos hay un código con un valor "test8", la consulta me lo toma como que lo encontró, cuando en realidad no es exactamente el que busqué.

Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Gracias!!!

Comment: Sin información del código de la función `findByCodigo` imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @Andrés Alcarraz ... acabo de añadir más código

Comment: Bien Fernando, pero sigue sin estar la definición del método `findByCodigo` para saber qué hace.

Comment: El servicio es enorme, pero añadí la porción donde uso el find que me da problemas...

Comment: Es que el problema no está en el uso, el problema está en  eel código que implementa la función, no podemos saber por qué hace lo que hace, si no sabemos lo que hace.

Comment: Perdón, no me di cuenta que esta pregunta estaba en el contexto de `SpringBoot` que implementa el método en función del nombre. Yo te sugeriría que configures para que se muestren las consultas que se ejecutan por la capa de persistencia, (https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) a ver que se está ejecutando cuando se llama al `findByCode`

Comment: Lo hice!!! Copio esa consulta generada, la ejecuto y no me devuelve nada como tiene que ser... por eso digo que es raro que en spring boot me devuelva un resultado

Comment: Podés agregar el sql que muestra a la pregunta por favor? Puede ser que tenga ese otro registro en algún tipo de cache? Es sistemático? es decir, pasa si en la base has `hola12` y buscás `hola122` también por ejemplo?

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz la query que arma spring boot es la indicada y al ejecutarla me resuelve lo correcto. Hice la prueba que me dijiste y comento los resultados más abajo...

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de darme cuenta de un posible motivo, pero que aún no entiendo por qué pasa...
A nivel base de datos, el campo CODIGO con el que tengo el inconveniente tiene establecido que admite un máximo de 5 dígitos. Cuando le voy dando valores parecidos me los admite todos hasta que llego a meterle seis dígitos, es decir (por ejemplo) si le pongo a1, a11, a111 ó a1111 todo funciona, hasta que le pongo a11111... es ahí donde rompe!!! Lo que no entiendo es porqué rompe por mi validación (interpretando que ese valor ya existe) y no lanza una excepción de SQL ya que el error es a nivel de base de datos.
De ante mano sé que debo poner en el request dto una validación `@size (value = 5)` para el valor CODIGO, pero igual me quedo con la duda de qué pasó.
Si alguien tiene algún indicio, por favor que lo comente.
Gracias!!!